# C: Sorting a pointer structure array by pointer key

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, struct

I have this structure:

```
typedef struct {
   char *str;
   ...
} nameType;
```

I create a new pointer instance, initialize the str pointer inside it (all of these have been done correctly, I can do printfs to check it).

```
nameType *names;
names = malloc( 10 * sizeof( nameType ) );
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    ...
    names[ i ].str = malloc( ... );
    ...
}
```

And then I want to sort it using bubblesort, but I'm having trouble doing it. Noted that I managed to do it using qsort, but after some days of debugging, testing, googling etc, I still can't find it. Sorting code:

```
for ( i = 0; i < n - 1; i++ ) {
    for ( j = n - 1; j > i; j-- ) {
        if ( strcmp( names[ i ].str, names[ j ].str ) > 0 ) {
            nameType *tmp;
            tmp = names[ i ];
            names[ i ] = names[ j ];
            names[ j ] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

(The above code is just an example of what I'm doing with sorting -- I've tried so many variations that my mind is going to blow.)

Comment: you ask about bubblesort or about problem with this code?

Comment: What's the trouble you're having ? What's the code you're using that performs the sort ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add the sorting code. I'm having a problem with sorting, everything else works fine, and I have checked it.

Comment: Just an observation (maybe irrelevant), shouldn't `j` start from `n-1` instead of `n`?

Comment: @another.anon.coward Typo in the post, fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`names` is used as an array of `nameType`, but

```
nameType *tmp;
tmp = names[ i ];
```

you assign `names[i]` to a pointer to `nameType`. Make it `nameType tmp;`.

And of course make sure you don't overstep the allocated space for `names`, as @another.anon.coward said, `j` should probably start from `n-1`.

Comment: Thank, you, that was it. (The "n" instead of "n-1" was a type on the 1st post)